# Can I transfer certain questions to a new account?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question that is tied to my old account. I canceled that account and created a new one some time later.how can I get a question from back then transfered to my current account?

Answer (score 7):

I think your only option here is to request that the accounts be merged.  This can only be done by an SE employee.

Just click on the support link at the bottom of the page to make the request.

IF you have deleted the previous account I am not sure if they will be able to help you out, not sure I have run into that situation before.